# How to run a script at the start of the visual studio command-line tool?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, batch-file, msbuild

I am using visual studio 2010
I need a script that launches the visual studio console and executes some commands
More specifically something like this:

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
msbuild smothing
cd somewhere
etc...
```

However after executing the first line and entering the visual studio mode the script stops

**How can I make it run msbuild and everything else in one go?**

Comment: Why not just use call %VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change the top line with this:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

Comment: You can use system variable in case if you have installed it to some other location upvoted.
%vs100comntools%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat